# pandas Multi-index DataFrame column level values still exists after selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiindex pd.DataFrame:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],[1,2,3]])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1, 2, 3, 4], columns=idx).fillna(0)
```

and I would like to select the 'a' part of the first level of the columns:

```
dfa = df[['a']]
```

The results look ok:

```
   a      
   1  2  3
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
4  0  0  0
```

However, where trying to look at the column of the new DataFrame `dfa`, I will still the column values `b` that is not supposed to be there.

```
dfa.columns.levels[0]
Index([u'a', u'b'], dtype='object')
```

Why is the old (unselected) level 0 column value `b` still there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `remove_unused_levels`

```
dfa.columns=dfa.columns.remove_unused_levels()
dfa.columns.levels
Out[227]: FrozenList([['a'], [1, 2, 3]])
```